# MediaCapture Preview destroyed when resolution is raised

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

My app needs to take photos and I've stolen most of MediaCapture goodness from the [uwp example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraManualControls). However, the default behavior creates a very low resolution photo (640x480 => 52KB).

I can set the preview to a higher resolution:

`mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, prop)`

but if I do this the preview becomes horribly grainy and takes forever to focus.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm writing the previewed image straight to the file, so I don't see how I can improve the resolution any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I swear, pushing "Post" on stackoverflow often helps me find the answer :-).  I don't really understand why, but I finally found someone recommending to use the Video settings instead of the Photo ones.  Sure enough!  That made a huge difference.

```
   var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings {
                VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id,
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
                AudioDeviceId = string.Empty
            };
    await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
```